# Shiny app UI not occupying entire browser area

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, there is a lot of whitespace on the right side of the screen. Is there a way to make the UI proportionately occupy the entire screen? I wish to make the input panel column and the big plot larger, and also add another small plot between the big plot and the input panel.

[This is how the UI looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZMAx.png)

The big plot is in a column of width 9 and input panel is in a column of width 3. I have used `fluidPage`. I read some answers to similar questions and tried `fillPage`, and other standard layouts, but none worked. Can someone please help with solving this problem? If I can just get how to use the entire screen, then the second smaller plot can easily be inserted in between by adding an additional column.

Here is the code for the first tab:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("XYZ"),
  mainPanel(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "ABC",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 9,
            fileInput("file_1", "Please choose files", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".csv", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
            plotOutput(
              outputId = "live_plot_1",
              height = '500px',
              width = '550px',
              click = 'plot_click_1',
              #dblclick = "plot1_dblclick_1",
              brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush_1",resetOnNew = TRUE)
            ),
            
            actionButton("zoom_reset_1", "Reset zoom"),
            verbatimTextOutput("click_info"),
            
            plotOutput(
              outputId = "live_plot_2",
              height = '250px',
              width = '250px',
              click = "plot_click_2",
              brush = brushOpts(id = "plot2_brush_2", resetOnNew = TRUE)
            ),
            actionButton("zoom_reset_2", "Reset zoom"),
            actionButton("buttonbutton", "Button")
            
          ),
          
          column(
            width = 3,
            inputPanel(
              uiOutput("Variables"),
              actionButton("next_button", "Next"),
            )
          )
        )
))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the mainPanel() function from wrapping the rest of the UI. The mainPanel() is usually used in combination with a sidebarPanel(), so it's not needed here, and when I omit that it fixes the width issue.

So the first part of your code would look like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("XYZ"),
  useShinyjs(),
  tabsetPanel(  
# ... (etc... rest of your code)
```